# What is the best resource to learn core data with starter project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa, core-data

I have been struggling with core data for week, but still haven't get a good understanding of core data.
I know Apple already provide a great series of guide [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/cdProgrammingGuide.html)

But it's too much information for me, and it's kind of boring.

Are there any good tutorial about core data, better to have a starter project and will guide you through out the tutorial.
Or are there any websites provide courses like [Codeschool](http://www.codeschool.com/), it's a great code learning website, but unfortunately it haven't get specific course for core data yet.

Comment: Can try http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started

Comment: Ray has a good one here [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started)

Comment: Codigator has good tutorial on this one, covering adding core data to managing data base from scratch in its two tutorials coredata series... it can be found here... http://www.codigator.com/tutorials/ios-core-data-tutorial-with-example/

Answer (score 3):

try this links really useful

http://www.codigator.com/tutorials/ios-core-data-tutorial-with-example/

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-core-data/

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/core-data_schema-versioning-and-lightweight-migrations/

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_5_iPhone_Core_Data_Tutorial

and raywenderlich tutorials will be good

http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please note that you should post the essential parts of the answer here, on this site, or your post risks being deleted [See the FAQ where it mentions answers that are 'barely more than a link'.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) You may still include the link if you wish, but only as a 'reference'. The answer should stand on its own without needing the link.

Answer (score 3):

you can use Ray's tutorial 
http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started

or

This one is also useful
http://www.codigator.com/tutorials/ios-core-data-tutorial-with-example/

Answer (score 0):

I learnt using this book from Wrox:

http://www.amazon.co.uk/Professional-iOS-Database-Application-Programming-ebook/dp/B00CC0GZIM

Using the examples and tutorials in the book I Googled the extra bits I needed to know and worked from there.